# Java replace Matcher

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to find replace part of what is matched.

***Example:***

```html
this is awesome look at this two letter words get replaced
```

the return would be

```html
this <h1>is</h1> awesome look <h1>at</h1> this two letter words get replaced
```

Notice how the `is` and `at` which would match regex `\b\w\w\b` would be matched are replaced.

This is the code I was working on. It's not finished but I am just a little confused and wondering if there is an easier way. I was searching the string and finding the matches.  Then I was adding it to an ArrayList and replace each one. The problem is one of the thing that I am replacing is `{` and I want to replace it with `{{}`

Now in a look this will continually replace the brackets because I keep adding them...
So my other thought was to replace them all one by one char by char and add to a new StringBuilder object?

```java
ArrayList<String> replacements = new ArrayList<String>();

String s = "::";

s += command;

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[!-~]");
Matcher match = p.matcher(this.execution);

while(match.find())
{
    replacements.add(match.group());
}

StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0; i<this.execution.length(); i++)
{ 
    String a  =new String(execution.charAt(i));
    if()
    { 
    }
}
s += "::" + this.execution;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get how could your code solve the requirements you explained above...

That said, it seems to be a easier way to do this kind of job by using the JAVA's [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%2C+java.lang.String%29) method, typically for the two-letter words:

```java
"this is awesome look at this two letter words get replaced"
.replaceAll("(\\b\\w{2}\\b)", "<h1>$1</h1>");
```

This prints:

```
this <h1>is</h1> awesome look <h1>at</h1> this two letter words get replaced
```

Comment: yea wasn't the smartest move. I was writing it for something else tho. I needed to check each char to make sure it wasn't a certain char then replace it. so i was adding it to the string builder while building it back up.